# ORDER BY date in sub-query?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm using Oracle 11g, come across the situation to order the data based on sub-query.

Assume having the two tables `STATUS_TABLE` and `TXN_TABLE`. I want to short the `TXN_TABLE` based on the `STATUS_TABLE`'s `DATE_INS` field.

Below is the sample query,

```
SELECT ID
FROM STATUS_TABLE
WHERE STATUS = 'Pass'
ORDER BY DATE_INS DESC
```

This query returns me a list of ID's in descending order based on the DATE_INS. So the above query has been extended little bit for TXN_TABLE as follows

```
SELECT *
FROM TXN_TABLE
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM STATUS_TABLE
             WHERE STATUS = 'Pass'
             ORDER BY DATE_INS DESC)
```

which gives me:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I gone through the document, they where telling that it is not possible to make a order class at sub-query. so is there any workaround for this scenario to make it work?

Comment on below, if you need any more details on this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you ordering the subquery? If join need to order for a field of STATUS_TABLE, you'd better think of joining the two tables, rather than using a subquery.

Comment: No need for that ORDER BY anyway, makes no sense at all.

Comment: The `order by` in the sub-query is totally useless.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: So what is the other choice?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this

```
SELECT tmp.* FROM
    (SELECT tx.*, st.DATE_INS AS DATE_INS_ST
    FROM TXN_TABLE tx, STATUS_TABLE st
    WHERE tx.ID = st.ID AND st.STATUS = 'Pass') tmp
ORDER BY DATE_INS_ST DESC
```

Comment: This will solve the error, but will give no ordering on the result

Comment: @Murali : please note, some user did wrong edit there. please check it now.

Comment: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined - getting this error at DATE_INS

Comment: Does TXN_TABLE has the same column name (i.e. DATE_INS) as STATUS_TABLE?

Comment: yes, it has on both the table. that column is common for all the tables. It is actually DateTime of particular record insertion into that table.

Comment: In that case you need to assigned another name for DATE_INS for STATUS_TABLE. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110500/discussion-between-wanna-coffee-and-maruli).

Answer (score 1):

Ordering the subquery will give no ordering on the final result;
you could rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM TXN_TABLE
    INNER JOIN STATUS_TABLE
USING(ID)
WHERE STATUS='Pass'
ORDER BY DATE_INS DESC
```

assuming, as rightly oberved by jarlh, that your ID columns can not have duplicate values

Comment: Note that this query is only equivalent as long as STATUS_TABLE has no ID duplicates. (No need to panic, id columns are usually unique.)